# MVT coordinates are not accurate with less zoom

Tags: postgis, mapbox, vector-tiles

I'm using MVT data to draw some markers on Google Map. I have all setup "correctly" but I have some problems when I zoom out. This is a screenshot of a zone with more zoom:

[image]

And the same zone with less zoom:

[image]

As you can see, the points get all distorted. Some of them even appear in the sea! I cannot figure out why this is happening, because the setup it's the same for every tile.

### Current setup

I have been following this [article](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis) to get the MVT from my PostgreSQL database. This is a step by step explanation of my code:

These are some common variables used to calculate the bounding box of every tile.

```js
const WORLD_MERCATOR_MAX = 20037508.3427892;
const WORLD_MERCATOR_MIN = -1 * WORLD_MERCATOR_MAX;
const WORLD_MERCATOR_SIZE = WORLD_MERCATOR_MAX - WORLD_MERCATOR_MIN;
const GEOM_COLUMN = "geom";
const TABLE = "records_addressvalue";
const SRID = 3857;
```

```js
const tileToEnvelope = (tile) => {
  const tilesOnWorld = 2 ** tile.zoom;
  const tileMercatorSize = WORLD_MERCATOR_SIZE / tilesOnWorld;
  return {
    xmin: WORLD_MERCATOR_MIN + tileMercatorSize * tile.x,
    xmax: WORLD_MERCATOR_MIN + tileMercatorSize * (tile.x + 1),
    ymin: WORLD_MERCATOR_MAX - tileMercatorSize * (tile.y + 1),
    ymax: WORLD_MERCATOR_MAX - tileMercatorSize * tile.y,
  };
};
```

This function computes the coordinates of the tile `/zoom/x/y` on the Mercator plane. That envelope is then transformed into an SQL bound by this other function:

```js
const envelopeToSqlBounds = (envelope) => {
  const densifyFactor = 4;
  envelope.segmentSize = (envelope.xmax - envelope.xmin) / densifyFactor;
  const { xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, segmentSize } = envelope;
  return `ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(${xmin}, ${ymin}, ${xmax}, ${ymax}, 3857), ${segmentSize})`;
};
```

Then, that query and the first variables are joined together to form the whole SQL query like this:

```js
const buildSqlQuery = (envelope) => {
  const envelopeQuery = envelopeToSqlBounds(envelope);
  return `
        WITH
        bounds AS (
            SELECT ${envelopeQuery} AS geom,
                   ${envelopeQuery}::box2d AS b2d
        ),
        mvtgeom AS (
            SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.${GEOM_COLUMN}, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom,
                   original_address
            FROM ${TABLE} t, bounds
            WHERE ST_Intersects(t.${GEOM_COLUMN}, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, ${SRID}))
        )
        SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom
  `;
};
```

For instance, for the tile `/0/0/0`, the resulting SQL query would be:

```sql
WITH
        bounds AS (
            SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(-20037508.3427892, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 3857), 10018754.1713946) AS geom,
                   ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(-20037508.3427892, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 3857), 10018754.1713946)::box2d AS b2d
        ),
        mvtgeom AS (
            SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom,
                   original_address
            FROM records_addressvalue t, bounds
            WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 3857))
        )
        SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom
```

As you may know, this will return a proto buffer that you can decode using the proto file from the spec. Then you obtain a list of features with geometries like this one `[9, x, y]`. According to the specs, the 9 it's a command and the two last numbers are the coordinates. To obtain them in the interval `[0, 4096]` you need to apply this transformation `(x >> 1) ^ -(x & 1)`.

In my Google Map, I'm using a canvas of size `256x256` pixels, so I need to convert the interval `[0, 4096]` to the interval `[0, 256]`. I can do that by just doing `x * 256 / 4096`.

## Conclusion

So, that's what I'm currently doing and it's not working so I suppose there is some mistake in the process I'm not seeing right now. Each time I zoom in the image gets more accurate so I do not know where the problem may be. I think maybe I should avoid the transformation `256 / 4096` and just change the default value in the SQL query (I have checked that and I get the same result).

What do you think may be the problem? Do you need more information?

## Interesting thing

I have realised that the same tile shows the points in different places! Pretty weird, the computations are the same for both of them! Take a look at the `(0,1)` tile. The others are not affected, only that one.

[image]

Comment: are you using pg_tileserv? is not you should be. it will take care of what you need

Comment: No, I'm not using it. I'm trying to build it on my own to understand all the process.